# Hosting an wcf service into a website issue : System.ArgumentException: ServiceHost only supports class service types

Tags: .net, wcf

I have something like this:

**MathServiceLibrary** (WCF Service Library)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMathService
{
        [OperationContract]
        int Add(int x, int y);
        [OperationContract]
        int Multiply(int x, int y);
}

public class MathService : IMathService
{
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        } 

        public int Multiply(int x, int y)
        {
            return x * y;
        }
}

<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior" 
            name="MathServiceLibrary.MathService">
       <endpoint 
           address="mex" 
           binding="mexHttpBinding" 
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       <endpoint 
           address="math" 
           binding="wsHttpBinding" 
           contract="MathServiceLibrary.IMathService" />
       <host>
          <baseAddresses>
             <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/" />
          </baseAddresses>
       </host>
    </service>
 </services>
```

If I run this I can see the WCF Test Client and everything is ok.

Now I want to host this service into IIS so I create a web site and add a reference to `MathServiceLibrary`.

I have this `ms.svc`

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="MathServiceLibrary.IMathService" %>
```

and this `web.config`

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior" name="MathServiceLibrary.MathService">
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MathServiceLibrary.IMathService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

When I right click on `ms.svc` view in browser I get this:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: ServiceHost only supports class service types.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: ServiceHost only supports class service types.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.GetService(Type
>   serviceType) +12229075
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2&
>   implementedContracts) +55
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses) +154
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +49
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +151
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +30
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String 
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +420
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1440
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +44
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +615
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/MathWebSite/ms.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation. The
>   exception message is: ServiceHost only supports class service types..]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +679246
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +190
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication
>   context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean 
>   ensureWFService) +234
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +355
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

I can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your ms.svc as below

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MathServiceLibrary.MathService" %    >
```

You have to give the class name instead of interface name

Answer (score 3):

Your .svc file is wrong. It references the interface, not the implementation. Change it to this:
`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MathServiceLibrary.MathService" %>`

Comment: I had my implementation on another project, not in the same namespace, is there any issue ?

Answer (score 3):

The svc file needs to have the class name rather than the interface name. A sample svc file has the below contents:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="SampleService.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The entry in your svc file is wrong:

instead of:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="MathServiceLibrary.IMathService" %>
```

you need to have:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="MathServiceLibrary.MathService" %>
```

You need to define the **service implementation class** in the `Service=` attribute - **NOT** the service contract!