# WCF Rest service not working

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

**ILeaveManagement** class

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ILeaveManagement
    {               
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "get")]
        List<ServiceReference1.LeaveRequest> GetLeaveDetails();
    }
```

**LeaveManagement**  class

```
public class LeaveManagement : ILeaveManagement
    {

    public List<ServiceReference1.LeaveRequest> GetLeaveDetails()
            {
                try
                {
                    var entities = new ServiceReference1.leaverequest_Entities(new Uri(serviceUrl));               
                    var result = entities.LeaveRequestCollection;
                    return result.ToList();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return new List<ServiceReference1.LeaveRequest>();
                }
            }
}
```

**configuration**

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="DRLExternalList.LeaveManagementBehavior" name="DRLExternalList.LeaveManagement">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="DRLExternalList.ILeaveManagement"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>

<behavior name="DRLExternalList.LeaveManagementBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
```

I have deployed the project in IIS 7.5. When i run the application , it is saying BadRequest.

I have verrified in fiddler. i saw 400 error.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using webHttpBinding in your endpoint instead of the wsHttpBinding, or add it as an additional one and change the address. I use a bindingNamespace in my project, but I don't think you need it.

```
    <endpoint address="XMLService"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="restXMLBehavior"
              contract="DRLExternalList.ILeaveManagement">
    </endpoint>
```

Add an Endpoint Behavior

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <!-- Behavior for the REST endpoint -->
    <behavior name="restXMLBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

I also annotate the OperationContract slightly differently, but it shouldn't make all that much of a difference.  I'll give it to you just in case...

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetLeaveDetails", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
```

To call the service, it would look like this using the XMLService endpoint name:

```
http://myWebHost.com/WebService/MyService.svc/XMLService/GetLeaveDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hosting an wcf service into a website issue : System.ArgumentException: ServiceHost only supports class service types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988300/hosting-an-wcf-service-into-a-website-issue-system-argumentexception-serviceh)

the above link helped me to solve my issue.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="restleave.ProductRESTService" %>
```